# One Website multiple Application pools

Tags: asp.net, application-pool

Does anybody know if its possible to have your website run on multiple separate application pools

Some Background
I am looking into start a shopping center style site. I intend to set up
100 folders, each folder on the site will be treated as a separate site.
http://www.MyShoppingCentre/JohnsMenswear
http://www.MyShoppingCentre/GerrysGardeningCenter

I would like to have JohnMenswear running in a separate application pool
to GerrysGardeningCenter even though they are both webpages under MyShoppingCentre

Any help gratefully appreciated

Answer (score 6):

Yes, create "Applications" out of each sub folder. Than the application can have a separate application pool, the same will work for Virtual Directories. Alternately you could also set up sub-domains and map each one to a separate website.